# Getting a Thread Exception in kivy randomly

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, kivy

I keep getting this thread Exception randomly during the start of my kivy App (I would say this exception occurs with a 1% chance)

```
 Exception in thread Thread-1:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
     self.run()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
     self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/input/providers/mtdev.py", line 324, in _thread_run
     process([l_points[x] for x in _changes])
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/input/providers/mtdev.py", line 198, in process
     touch = MTDMotionEvent(device, tid, args)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/input/motionevent.py", line 287, in __init__
     self.depack(args)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/input/providers/mtdev.py", line 50, in depack
     self.sx = args['x']
 KeyError: 'x'
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to show the code the is causing this error? Even better yet would be a sample that we could cut and paste and run for ourselves!

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no Idea wich sample is causing this error, and my code is around 2000 lines...

Comment: Well you say it happens during start up, right? And it looks like it's either related to some sort of threading that you're doing or maybe the kivy install itself (reinstall could fix? Just a guess though). Are you doing anything right on start up with threads?

Comment: Does this happen if you run a simple testapp instead of your complicated one?

Comment: I'm not doing anything thread related during the start of my app (neither later in my app btw), I will try to reinstall kivy. 

@inclement, As i said this error appears once in a while, so it's difficult to reproduce it with a test app